# Почему не могу записать данные в текстовый файл с помощью сервера?

Tags: python, ооп, атрибуты, txt, строки

Добрый день я новичок в программировании на пайтон, может кто-нибудь объяснить, почему я не могу записать в txt файл ввод клиента? Вкратце поясню чего я хочу добиться: обрабатывать с помощью сервера запросы клиента, записывая их в текстовый файл, запись происходит со стороны сервера.
Вроде бы код выполняется, тестировал его отдельно без использования сокетов и это работало, но видимо сокет закрывается до того, как атрибут `data_to_write`, объекта `handler` получает переменную `get_command`. Либо же сокет вообще не передает переменную в качестве атрибута методу `change_file()`
Подскажите что я делаю не так?
Ниже представлен код сервера:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

path_to_file = "qwerty.txt"

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def set_up(self):
        self.server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9099))
        self.server.listen(5)
        print("Server is listening")
        self.accept_sockets()

    def listen_socket(self, listened_socket=None):
        print("Listening user")
        while True:
            data = listened_socket.recv(5000)
            self.get_command = data.decode("utf-8")
            print(f"\nUser sent <{self.get_command}>")

    def send_to_client(self, send_socket=None):
        while True:
            send_to_client = input("Введите значение:").encode("utf-8")
            send_socket.send(send_to_client)

    def accept_sockets(self):
        while True:
            user_socket, address = self.server.accept()
            print(f"User <{address[0]}> connected!")

            listen_thread = Thread(
                target=self.listen_socket,
                args=(user_socket,)
            )
            listen_thread.start()

            send_thread = Thread(
                target=self.send_to_client,
                args=(user_socket,)
            )
            send_thread.start()


class Handler:
    def change_file(self, data_to_write):
        with open(path_to_file, "ab") as f:
            f.write(data_to_write)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Server()
    server.set_up()

    handler = Handler()
    handler.change_file(server.get_command)
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print("Client connection")

    def set_up(self):
        self.client.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9099))

        send_thread = Thread(target=self.send_data)
        send_thread.start()

        listen_thread = Thread(target=self.listen_socket)
        listen_thread.start()

    def send_data(self):
        while True:
            msg = input("Enter your messages:  ")
            self.client.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))

    def listen_socket(self):
        while True:
            data = self.client.recv(5000)
            print("Полученное сообщение: ", data.decode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    client.set_up()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой маленький пример
Server:

```
import asyncio


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, ip: str, port: int, limit: int):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.limit = limit

    async def _reading_message(self, reader: asyncio) -> str:
        """
        Функция получения сообщения по открытому соединению

        :param reader: asyncio
        :return: received_message: str
        """
        received_message = ''
        while True:
            message = await reader.read(100)
            message = message.decode()
            received_message += message
            if '\r\n\r\n' in received_message:
                break
        return received_message

    async def _handler(self, reader: asyncio, writer: asyncio) -> None:
        """
        Хендрел который вызываеться при получении нового соединения.
        Функция осуществляет получение данных вызывом
        self._reading_message с timeout=1 и отправку результатов пользователю.

        :param reader:
        :param writer:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            received_message = await asyncio.wait_for(self._reading_message(reader), timeout=1)
            # Сохраняем сообщение в файл
            write_message_to_file = Handler().change_file(received_message)
            if write_message_to_file is True:
                writer.write('Ваше сообщение успешно получено!'.encode())
            else:
                writer.write('Не удалось обработать ваше сообщение!'.encode())
            await writer.drain()
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
        except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
            msg_error = 'Превышено время ожидания сервера на получение данных от клиента.'
            writer.write(msg_error.encode())

    async def main(self):
        """ Функция запуска сервера"""
        server = await asyncio.start_server(client_connected_cb=self._handler,
                                            host=self.ip,
                                            port=self.port,
                                            limit=self.limit)
        address = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print(f'Сервер включен {address}')

        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()


class Handler:

    def change_file(self, data_to_write):
        with open('1.txt', "w") as f:
            f.write(data_to_write)
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(Server(ip='127.0.0.1', port=8888, limit=128).main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Сервер остановлен')
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print("Превышено вермя ожидания для получения данный!")
```

Client:

```
import asyncio


class Client(object):
    """
    Класс опроса сервера проверки
    """
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.server = '127.0.0.1'
        self.port = 8888
        self.message = message

    async def send_message(self) -> str:
        """
        Отправляет запрос на сервер
        :return: received_message
        """
        # Открываем соединение
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.server, self.port)
        # Отправляем данные и очиищаем буфер
        writer.write(self.message.encode())
        await writer.drain()
        # дожидаемся ответа и декодируем его
        received_message = await reader.read(100)
        received_message = received_message.decode()
        print(received_message)
        # закрываем соеденинения и возвращаем результат
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()
        return received_message


asyncio.run(Client(message='Прррииивет\r\n\r\n').send_message())
```

Проблема твоего кода в том что функция которую ты вызываешь ничего не возращает. Используй `asyncio` и жить станет проще. У тебя не будет блокирующих  соединений и не нужно будет запускать потоки, они тебе не нужны.